# Unexpected result when calculating shortest distance between point and curve

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My math book has following problem: "Find distance between point $(2,0)$ and curve $y=\sqrt{x}$."

I assume this asks for the shortest distance because I cannot think of any other distance that would be meaningful.

I tried solving it this way:

Define distance as function of $x$

$$ D(x) = \sqrt{(x-2)^2+(\sqrt{x}-0)^2} $$

Find derivate of $D(x)$

$$ D'(x) = \frac{2x-3}{2\sqrt{x^2-3x+4}}$$

Shortest distance is where the derivate equals zero

$$ 0 = \frac{2x-3}{2\sqrt{x^2-3x+4}} $$
$$ x = \frac{3}{2} $$

Get distance using the value of $x$

$$ D\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) = \sqrt{\left(\frac{3}{2}-2\right)^2+\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}-0\right)^2} = \frac{\sqrt7}{2} \approx 1.3$$

But my book states that result is $1.56$.

Is there error in my calculation? Or could there be some other meaningful distance I should be calculating instead?

Comment: Must be a typo of some sort, since the distance from $(2,0)$ to $(2,\sqrt{2})$ is $\sqrt{2} < 1.56$.

Comment: Notice that it is faster to minimize $D^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach and answer are correct.

I created a small Desmos animation (linked [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sfmclynhv6)) that shows the distance between $(2,0)$ and $y = \sqrt{x}$ along the graph. You will notice that the minimum is $\approx 1.32 \approx \frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}$.